# Captialization after a colon

Tags: orthography, capitalization, colons

Should I captialize the word after a colon if its a dependent clause? For example

> You are banned: violating our Terms and Services.

OR

> You are banned: Violating our Terms and Services.

Which one is correct?

Comment: You shouldn't have a colon at all. It should be "You are banned for violating ..."

Comment: If you do use a colon, the following should be a complete sentence.

Comment: What does this have to do with grammar? It looks like it concerns only punctuation and capitalization, which have nothing to do with grammar, only with orthography. Grammar — syntax and morphology — is about fitting together different linguistic elements: syntax is how to fit words together to make a phrase, and morphology is about how to fit morphemes together to make a word.  If it's the same words in the same order, the grammar is the same no matter how someone should happen to write something down. That said, you do have a grammatical error because you've left a word out.

Comment: It depends on what style guide you follow. *The Chicago Manual of Style*, for instance, says to leave the first letter in lowercase if what follows is a statement, but to put it in uppercase if what follows is a question.

Comment: And ignore any advice that what *follows* a colon needing to be a complete clause. That's not true according to any style guide. Most would say that what *precedes* the colon should be a complete clause, but that's also a matter of style, and not the case universally.